# Why Google Finance puts to two decimal places for the trading volumes?

Tags: stocks, google-finance

Since we can't trade 0.5 stocks or 1/3 stocks, why the Google Finance would mark the volumes as `20,000.00` not just `20,000`?

Maybe a stupid question but I am just wondering why not just remove the `00` to make it easier to read as I saw in my brokers panel?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many brokerages offer automatic dividend reinvestment.

It is very infrequent that these dividends are exactly a whole share. So, if you have signed up for automatic dividend reinvestment, many brokerages will reinvest your dividends and assign to you a fractional share. I can't speak for how these shares work with regards to voting, but I can say that the value of these fractional holdings does change with stock price as if one genuinely could hold a fraction of a share.